# Track Youtube Share button in Embedded

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, youtube, analytics

A Youtube Embedded video has this share button:

[image: Youtube's video embedded share button]

When it is selected, it shows up this frame:

[image: Youtube's video embedded share options]

How can I track clicks over these buttons through JavaScript or some API?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you find anything? I am searching same.

Comment: No, I haven't. Actually, I gave up. I wish you could find the answer. Best of luck.